# Android SMS Application

Tags: java, android, sms

I want to create an android application that a user can use to text others. It should function like the Whatsapp app for android or any other sms application I believe.

I'm not sure how I should go about creating it though. I have heard there is an sms api in android, but I wasnt sure if that would send an sms to the default texting app to the phone or if it would send it to the same application on the phone. Basically I would like the application to function like the default texting service on a phone.  I figured I could set up a proper interface and allow the user to enter the sms into an edittext and on clicking send it would be sent to a database on a server and the recepient's app would connect to the server and retreive the message.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction on how to create this app and are there any sample codes for texting apps ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `SmsManager` class allows you to send SMSs from you own app. One code example can be found at http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/

Edit: I see that you also wants to know how to receive a SMS.This blog post http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android might be more useful than the  first one I mentioned. It teaches how to setup the broadcast receiver and parse the PDUs. It also teaches how to test using the emulator. This will save a lot of money. I think this was the post I read the first time I played with SMS on Android.

Comment: can u tel how to send message to a particular contact no ,and that contact person have to recieve the message through code..is it possible

Comment: @shanthi Can you add more details on what you want? I did not understand what you meant to do. The SmsManager works with phone numbers, so you have to retrieve the phone number from the Contacts Provider. The link above show how to receive a message too.

Comment: that links are just to show how to send sms ,wat is the structure of the sms ...Actually wat iam asking is i want to send a msg to particular no,,,already i have check that examples before it self,but the message is not delvering to a particular no...

Answer (score 2):

"are there any sample codes for texting apps?"
I found a few online, you can download the apk's on the left panel in google code or browse the github one. I can't really help you out with anything else, im brand new to android. Links:

[smsforfree](http://code.google.com/p/smsforfree/)

[texteasy](http://code.google.com/p/texteasy/)

code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/

github.com/WhisperSystems/TextSecure

your going to have to copy and paste the last two ones, stackoverflow will only let me post two links :/

Comment: Thank you for the links, this should give me a very good start

Comment: no problem man, I tried searching for just a simple texting app and could only find one.

Answer (score 0):

To Send SMS

```
String phoneNo = “xxxxxxxxxx”;
String Message = “Hello Android.”;

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, Message, 
 PendingIntent.getBroadcast( MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent("com.example"), 0),null);
```

You also need a permission in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```